# Printing objects without ansible_host

Tags: jq, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to use jq to process JSON from the VMware Ansible inventory module so I can produce a list of objects (VMs) that don't have ansible_host defined.

The closest I've been able to get is:

```
{
  "config.cpuHotAddEnabled": true,
  "config.cpuHotRemoveEnabled": false,
  "config.hardware.numCPU": 1,
  "config.instanceUuid": "500e4e98-50ec-a3a7-9d45-b0ac36c2d192",
  "config.name": "tu-openldap-01",
  "config.template": false,
  "guest.guestId": "rhel6_64Guest",
  "guest.guestState": "notRunning",
  "guest.hostName": "tu-openldap-01",
  "guest.ipAddress": null,
  "name": "tu-openldap-01",
  "runtime.maxMemoryUsage": 2048
}
{
  "config.cpuHotAddEnabled": true,
  "config.cpuHotRemoveEnabled": false,
  "config.hardware.numCPU": 1,
  "config.instanceUuid": "500efaa5-baac-163b-65c0-7ed2a19f1d7d",
  "config.name": "tu1vcm7tst2001",
  "config.template": false,
  "guest.guestId": "rhel7_64Guest",
  "guest.guestState": "running",
  "guest.hostName": "rhel7-template",
  "guest.ipAddress": null,
  "name": "tu1vcm7tst2001",
  "runtime.maxMemoryUsage": 4096
}
```

using the following:

```
jq '._meta.hostvars[] | select(.ansible_host | not)' prod-inventory_201905070920.json
```

This is almost where I want it, but the problem is how do I print these plus the key for the object itself?

If I do:

```
jq '._meta.hostvars | select(.ansible_host | not)' prod-inventory_201905070920.json
```

I get these:

```
"tw1pttest1001_420e92f4-453e-1267-4331-d6253d771882": {
    "ansible_host": "<omitted>",
    "config.cpuHotAddEnabled": true,
    "config.cpuHotRemoveEnabled": false,
    "config.hardware.numCPU": 2,
    "config.instanceUuid": "500ef630-16c1-cb91-be9c-e9e667b551d9",
    "config.name": "tw1pttest1001",
    "config.template": false,
    "guest.guestId": "windows9Server64Guest",
    "guest.guestState": "running",
    "guest.hostName": "<omitted>",
    "guest.ipAddress": "<omitted>",
    "name": "tw1pttest1001",
    "runtime.maxMemoryUsage": 49152
  },
  "tw1swsrm1001_420e18d2-0c96-0df5-e6c7-1ff8fc070cdb": {
    "ansible_host": "<omitted>",
    "config.cpuHotAddEnabled": true,
    "config.cpuHotRemoveEnabled": false,
    "config.hardware.numCPU": 4,
    "config.instanceUuid": "500e231d-1eda-4e66-3f4a-8c68392a70b5",
    "config.name": "tw1swsrm1001",
    "config.template": false,
    "guest.guestId": "windows9Server64Guest",
    "guest.guestState": "running",
    "guest.hostName": "<omitted>",
    "guest.ipAddress": "<omitted>",
    "name": "tw1swsrm1001",
    "runtime.maxMemoryUsage": 16384
  },
```

Any suggestions?  I feel like it's something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are searching for items found in the `._meta.hostvars` object, you can filter the objects by key/value by using something like `with_entries/1`.

```
$ jq '._meta.hostvars | with_entries(select(.value.ansible_host | not))
' prod-inventory_201905070920.json
```

This will in effect take the `hostvars` object and only keep properties that match that condition (does not have an `ansible_host` property value).